# Want to split character by space and convert group of characters to specific number

Tags: r

I have a problem I can't seem to understand how to do in R.  I'll try and write it in pseudocode.

1. take contents from one cell of matrix$column
2. transform() group character i.e. "RA FG+ FZFG BR" using if statement, ie RA = 1, FG+ 3, FZ = 1, FG = 2, BR = 2"
3. sum total for each cell
4. repeat for length of column

I've tried using library(Stringr) package and the function word(), not sure how I can loop through this.

```
library(stringr)
strip <- function(data){
  for (i in length(data))
    word(data, i, sep = " ")
    print(data[i])
  return(data)
}
strip("RA FG+ FZFG BR")
```

Cheers for looking

Ps Due to all of your awesome help, I found gsub("\FG", " ", x) worked well for the FZFG pairings.

PPs may not be technically correct but converting factor to as.list() then to numeric gave an interesting result that I'm sticking with for the moment.

Comment: What is the expected output Did you meant `table(strsplit(str1, "\\s+")[[1]])`

Comment: expect output for one cell would be integer 8

Comment: Can you give a vector that you need to work on and the expected results?

Comment: What I meant is for you to give an example of a vector. Will you always have the letters above?ie `"RA FG+ FZFG BR"` or will there be other letters? If yes which ones and how will you replace them?

Comment: oh sorry, no they are all different.  I'll give you an example.  I was too distracted trying to figure it out myself.  Sorry I didn't see the response until now. FG+ FG BR, SN UP, RA, (comma indicate new cell) Some don't have anything

Answer (score 3):

One solution could be using `gsubfn` and `eval` as:

```
library(gsubfn)

eval(parse(text = 
   gsub(" ","+",gsubfn("\\w+\\+?", 
   list("RA" = 1, "FG+" = 3, "FZFG" = 2, "BR" = 2), 
   "RA FG+ FZFG BR"))))

#Result:
# 8
```

One can use `matrix$column` in place of hardcoded `x` in above expression and replace another column in your dataframe.

```
matrix$sum <- eval(parse(text = 
      gsub(" ","+",gsubfn("\\w+\\+?",
      list("RA" = 1, "FG+" = 3, "FZFG" = 2, "BR" = 2), 
      matrix$column))))
```

Comment: This beats my code by about 30 lines.  Very neat, I like the this one for readability.  However, unfortunately FZFG need to be separated. Or do they.  In the end I wrote my own piece of trash code

Answer (score 1):

consider this and apply it on your matrix with for loop:

```
a <- "ab//*--cd#%@"
```

Now, I want to replace values as follows:
a=1, b=2, c=3, d=4:

```
b <- gsub("a",  "1", a)
b <- gsub("b",  "2", b)
b <- gsub("c",  "3", b)
b <- gsub("d",  "4", b)
```

cut all the unwanted symbols in the cell:

```
 b <- gsub("\\D", "", b)
```

make the cell numeric (so we could do math on it):

```
 b <- as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(b, "")))
```

now it is ready to get a sum:

```
 sum(b)
```

Comment: I don't understand the above code, I think this problem maybe out of my league

Comment: Wait I think I'm catching on @Mahdi, how do I put this as answer.  It says something about "check mark"

Comment: just run the code line by line, and see what it does, I think you will get the idea behind it.

Comment: will only work for single characters.. `a <- "a aa b//*--cd#%@"` for example would give  `1 1 1 2 3 4`

Comment: I have mentioned above that you can simply implement it with a for loop on your matrix

Answer (score 1):

I have some doubts regarding with the values of the groups of letters, however I came up with a general answer, this would be the code:

```
Strip <- function(word){
 word <- toupper(word)# Just in case

 group <- c("RA","FZ","FG","BR")
 value <- c("1","1","2","2")

 for(i in 1:length(group)){
  word <- gsub(group[i],value[i],word)
 }

 word <- gsub(" ","",word)
 word <- strsplit(word,"\\+")[[1]] #"+" is a special character you need to use "\\" for select the exact string.
 word <- sum(as.numeric(word))
 return(word)
}
```

Then you can `apply` this function in a `data frame` by columns just like this:

```
new_x <- data.frame(matrix(NA,nrow(x),ncol(x)))
new_x[,1:ncol(x)] <- apply(x[,1:ncol(x)],2,Strip)
```

In case you need other `values` for the `groups` just change the `Strip function`.

Hope this can help you.

Comment: Yeah, I have different values for each pair value.  They were just dummy values for testing.  So the "group" list matches the "value" list?

Comment: Exactly for this example **RA** matches the value **1** and so on. This avoids to use `gsub` for each value, i.e. `gsub("RA","1",word)` then `gsub("FZ","1",word)`

Answer (score 1):

ok here is a solution from my understanding of your problem. 
Let's say we have a data frame `mat` with strings in column `colA`

```
mat <- structure(list(colA = c("RA FG+ FZFG BR", " FG+ FZFG BR RA", 
                            "RFA FGP+ FFG BR", "RA FGs1+ FSZFG BR")), 
             class = "data.frame", .Names = "colA", 
             row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

like this: (first row is your example, so should give 8).

```
               colA
1    RA FG+ FZFG BR
2    FG+ FZFG BR RA
3   RFA FGP+ FFG BR
4 RA FGs1+ FSZFG BR
```

the function to convert all seeked words to numbers

```
change_it <- function(x){
 x <-  gsub("^RA","1", x)
 x <-  gsub("^FG\\+","3", x)
 x <-  gsub("^FZFG","2", x) 
 x <-  gsub("^BR","2", x) 
 x <-  gsub("^FG","2", x) 
 x <- as.numeric(x)
}
```

the ^ is to make sure we only count separate and first occurence, so that RARA is not replaced by 11 for example, or that DSRA is not replace by DS1

and now apply it (using dplyr):

```
mat2 <- mat %>%
  mutate(colB = strsplit(colA," ")) %>%
  mutate(colB = sapply(colB, change_it)) %>%
  rowwise %>% 
  mutate(colC = sum(colB,na.rm = TRUE))
```

Intermediate result (before rowwise)

```
               colA           colB
1    RA FG+ FZFG BR     1, 3, 2, 2
2    FG+ FZFG BR RA NA, 3, 2, 2, 1
3   RFA FGP+ FFG BR  NA, NA, NA, 2
4 RA FGs1+ FSZFG BR   1, NA, NA, 2
```

and the result

```
  colA              colB       colC
  <chr>             <list>    <dbl>
1 RA FG+ FZFG BR    <dbl [4]>  8.00
2 " FG+ FZFG BR RA" <dbl [5]>  8.00
3 RFA FGP+ FFG BR   <dbl [4]>  2.00
4 RA FGs1+ FSZFG BR <dbl [4]>  3.00
```

There will be some NA warnings from the numeric conversion
and it wont work if you have isolated numbers like let's say "RA FG 32 FD" because it will convert it to numeric and count it. (would need more filtering against that. You could make explicit tests in change_it instead of gsub to remedy..)

Comment: That is pretty awesome! Nice code.  With the "FG\\" does that take care of the plus sign? I'm cursing myself I didn't learn regex before starting this course.

Comment: Thks. The \ is an escape for special characters so that gsub knows how to deal with it, then the + is defined with \.  Of course you have to know that + is special...  I find this [page](http://www.endmemo.com/program/R/gsub.php) explains well. Regular expressions are pretty cumbersome to use. Unless you use them all the time you'll have to look it up everytime (at least I have to) so I wouldn't bit myself up too much ;). But knowing they exist is good. You could probably have a much neater change_it function with more advanced regex...